# Beautiful Soup Conditional Query

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautiful Soup.
I need to get data from HTML file.

```
<div class="ques_ans_block">

   <div class="question">
      <p>is this correct ?</p>
   <div>
    <p class="answer"></p>

   <div class="moreinfo" style="display: block;">
        <p class="answer"> <p>
        <p class="answer"></p>
   </div>

</div>
```

condition is , there can be "moreinfo" div  present or abscent.

so i need to find question and answer(including answer from "moreinfo" if present) innertext for each ques_ans_block ?

Comment: You just have to write python logic to do that.

Comment: i just know the basics but not the conditions associated with it.

Comment: does my answer give you a hint as to how to go about solving the problem?

Comment: yes. Thnx @shravster.

Comment: have you made any attempt at all? You seem to be asking for someone to write all the code for you which is not really what SO is for.

Comment: well i tried using  if condition. i almost got an answer. Only thing is there are "ul" and "li" elements in "moreinfo" .I need to parse it . I am working on it.

Comment: Add your code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give output as json containing Question, answer and FaqID.

```
import bs4
import json
import codecs
arrayList = []
bsp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('input.html'))
ques_ans_block = bsp.find_all("div", {"class": "ques_ans_block"})
s = ""
count = 1
for i in ques_ans_block:
    data = {}
    q = i.select('.question')   
    for a in q:
        s+=a.text+"\n"
    for a in q:
        a.extract()
    data["Question"] = s
    del i['.question']
    v = ""
    a = i.select('p')
    for a in a:
        v+=a.text+"\n"  
    a = i.select('li')
    for a in a:
        v+=a.text+"\n"
    data["Answer"] = v
    data["FaqId"] = count           
    print "\n"
    arrayList.append(data)
    count = count + 1
    s = ""

#print  arrayList
with codecs.open('output.json','wt','utf-8') as outfile:
    json.dump(arrayList, outfile, indent=4)
```